# What to do with wxWidgets after building it

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, wxwidgets

I'm currently trying to add a UI to my already complete program. So I've been searching on the internet for like 2 hours and still don't get how to use wxWidgets after building it using MinGW.

I tried using `-I` arguments for the gcc compilers so I could include the stuff that I apparently built and it can compile the program, but I can't seem to open the .exe file because it says it's incompatible with my current Windows OS.

I feel like I'm missing something here. I've read instructions on GitHub, but it all stops at how to build WxWidgets on MinGW and it doesn't explain anywhere how to use it after building it.

EDIT:
@DavidC.Rankin Tried it your way and even tried using the make file like this:

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\samples\minimal>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc
```

But now it gives me errors like this:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxmsw31ud_core
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxbase31ud
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxtiffd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxjpegd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxpngd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxexpatd
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile.gcc:221: recipe for target 'gcc_mswud\minimal.exe' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswud\minimal.exe] Error 1
```

It seems to be that the linker is not working properly. But I have no idea why.

EDIT2: for the record. Here is the command I used to build wxWidgets.

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\build\msw>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc CFG=32 CPPFLAGS="-DHAVE_TR1_TYPE_TRAITS" CXXFLAGS="-Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -fno-keep-inline-dllexport" MONOLITHIC=1 SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release`
```

Comment: When you build wxWidgets there should be somewhere inside the wxWidgets directory some header files and libraries that you need to reference from your own program.  What does the wxWidgets directory structure look like after building it?

Comment: wxWidgets is simply a graphics toolkit, just like Gtk or Qt. Once it is compiled you will have a directory with its header files (e.g. `wxwidgets.h` and other `*.h` files) Those are the *include* headers for the toolkit. You will also find a compiled `.dll`, probably `wxwidgets.dll`, that is the library (similar to the `wxwidgets.so` *shared object library* on Linux). That is what you *link* with your code. You will have to provide the compiler option `-I/path/to/the/headers` (as the *include search path*) and `-L/path/to/the/dll` as the *library search path* in order to use them.

Comment: I would suggest [Compiling wxWidgets with MinGW - WxWiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW) and [Compiling code using Mingw and wxWidgets on command line Windows](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=43374) as your beginning reads. (suggesting your google-foo is a bit weak tonight)

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I'll try all 3 of those and see what happens. I've already built the wxWidgets itself so it's probably a problem with linking it. Be back when I'm done trying it out.

`g++ -L C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_dll -I C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\include -o MChat.exe MChat.cpp -DUNICODE`

Comment: EDIT: Tried compiling using this line. Now it tells me that there are a lot of undefined references. I think I'm missing something to link. @DavidC.Rankin
`g++ -L C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_dll -I C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\include -o MChat.exe MChat.cpp -DUNICODE` I need to try the other suggestions later. I have to go for now. Be back again in about 12 hours.

Comment: You could load up some of the wxwidgets sample projects

Comment: The order of your `-L` and `-l` (little L) is significant. I'm fairly sure it will need to be similar to `g++  -Wall -Wextra -o MChat -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\include MChat.cpp -LC:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_dll -lgcc_ -DUNICODE`. (the `.exe` is added to the `-o` by default). (note the `-lgcc_` which looks odd. I would expect the `.dll` to be `wxwidgets.dll` rather than `gcc_` which sound like a build library rather than the result) You may need `MChat.cpp` after the `-l`, but check the references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you need to do is add the wxWidgets GUI code to your program.

Then when you done it, issue `exactly` the same command you used to build the wxWidgets in order to build you software. You will also need to check the link VZ (Vadim) pointed you to, because it contains an important pieces of info.

If you get an error during the build/link phases - please give the complete error message.

Comment: I think I get how it works now. I'll try that. But the problem now is, why is the sample program not building properly? Am I doing something wrong? edit: I will also be checking all the links provided. I'm still not back from work so it may take a while. Thanks!

Comment: It worked! I understand now. Thank you very much. So, all I had to do is copy the needed files into the directory of my project and actually build it from the ground. Then compile the main program itself.

Comment: @funnypigrun, you didn't have to copy anything. All you had to do is to build wxWidgets. Then build your own program. That's it. You also have to make sure that your code is following the wxWidgets samples, like `#include "wx/wx.h"`. Then you needed to add "-I" and "-L/-l" options to the compilation command. All this would've been easier if you had an IDE (Code::Blocks, CodeLite or MSVC), especially since you are newbie in the programming world and in the wxWidgets world in particular.

Comment: I think I can modify the sample makefiles to compile them without much problem. Also if I can get the wx-config working properly, it should be fine. I didn't want to use external tools to do stuff automatically so you guys helped me out a lot. Thank you. One has to eventually learn how exactly Code::Blocks and other tools work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The installation instructions describe what do you need to do to build your application using wxWidgets, see the [last section](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.1/docs/msw/install.txt#L491).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the output of `wx-config`.

- `wx-config --cxxflags` will give a list of the include directories
- `wx-config --libs "all"` will give a list libraries.

If you're using GNU make, you can set variables to hold them.

```
# wxWidgets
WXCXX      := $(shell wx-config --cxx)
WXCXXFLAGS := $(shell wx-config --cxxflags)

# ld has -o option, be careful
WXLD      := $(shell wx-config --ld)
WXLDLIBS  := $(shell wx-config --libs all)

.cpp.o:
    $(WXCXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(WXCXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECTS)
    $(WXLD) $@ $(OBJECTS) $(WXLDLIBS) $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: I'm sorry it's my first time to use external libraries in C++ and I have no idea of what you mean by "use the output of  `wx-config`. I stumbled upon this config thing in google but everyone is using terms I don't know or is for Linux. I'm using command prompt in windows 10. I still have the problem I added in the EDIT.

Comment: @funnypigrun If you open a command prompt (terminal) and type `wx-config --cxxflags` it will output a line with a bunch of `-I` and `-D`. Add the whole thing when compiling an object from the source. When you want to link the objects together into an executable, add the output from `wx-config --libs "all"`.

Comment: I will try it when I get to my computer and be back.

Comment: I typed `wx-config --cxxflags' but my command prompt says that that command does not exist. Was I supposed to set a PATH for that to work?